# How do I extract Facebook profile picture timestemp using the JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I Extract Facebook profile picture timeStemp using the Facebook JavaScript API?

Following code i am using to get facebook profile-picture.

```
$scope.getInfo =  function() {  
    FB.api('/me', 'GET', {fields: 'first_name,last_name,name,id,picture.width(100).height(100)'}, function(response) {
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "<img src='" + response.picture.data.url + "'>";
          console.log(response)
        });

}
```

or is there any way that i can get timestemp of profile picture ?? Please help me out :)

Comment: does the facebook api mention anything about it?

Comment: i dont think so...check this out ...

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

Comment: The Photo object has fields created_time and updated_time - but you can’t get there via `/me/profile`. You would need to read the user’s albums first, find the profile picture one, and look what the current photo in that album is. But that will of course require additional permissions from the user.

Comment: @CBroe yes we do required permissions .. we can get album last updated time.

Comment: FB.api(
    "/{{Album-id}}",{fields:"count,created_time,updated_time,description,event,from,type"},
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
        console.log("ProfilePicture")
        console.log(response)
      }
    }
);